# Facebook like button click

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When I clicked on the Facebook like button from my website one more window to like that page, is that possible to like directly from my website without open that popup.

See the Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please include your code and a test link, or some other way to reproduce the issue

Comment: Facebook sometimes asks users to confirm they actually wanted to like something, when they detect or suspect click-jacking or something like that. Testing extensively can also trigger this. There is nothing you can actively do about this.